# Extract fonts files from PDF using iText or PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf

Is it possible to extract valid font files (ttf,otf or cff formats) from a PDF using the iText or PDFBox Java libraries?

Comment: No you cannot do that.

Comment: You might want to read [this recent Adobe Forums thread](http://forums.adobe.com/message/5629652#5629652).